# Handle Touch-bar volume and brightness slider

Tags: swift, private, macbookpro-touch-bar

How can I handle the functions when user change volume/brightness with TouchBar slider?
I tired to use MediaKeyTap.framework but it works only on virtual/physical brightness and volume buttons and not TouchBar slider.
I think DFRFoundation is the framework that handle those events, am I right? how can I do it?